# What causes traffic from India to a set of URLs with a common path and a strange search term on a new Google Analytics setup?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-spam

I added Google Analytics to my site a few weeks ago, and since the beginning I've been seeing some very strange pageviews that make up over 80% of my traffic. Almost all of it is from India, and all of it is attempting to visit `/blpud/glotir.php?[something]` with `[something]` being some strange search term. (Music, pictures, etc.) I assume this is some kind of bot traffic, especially because almost all of the traffic goes to one search term.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? I've seen other reports of large amounts of bot traffic, but I haven't seen anything about this specifically. It's not a problem--I have it filtered out in all my important analytics, I'm just curious.

Comment: At first blush, looking around, this looks like a vulnerability test. It appears that some compromised computer, and possibly more than one, are testing computers on the net for vulnerabilities to further spread their virus. If these files do not exist and you get a 404, then no worries. If the file exists, then you may want to see if this file should be available online and possibly disable the file. I do not see a known vulnerability for this in the NVD database. If this file exists, please check with the vendor for specific information and warn them of the attempts. Cheers!!

Comment: For the record, it is always important to ask about strange things found in GA and in your log files. You are checking your log files regularly - right? You will find important stuff in the log files GA will never tell you about. I recommend using Piwik the log file analyzer. It is possibly the best out there and absolutely completely free. Feel free to ask questions like this whenever you see something you do not understand. We prefer that to your getting hacked, scrapped, or scammed somehow!

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete those directories and/or install an anti-malware plug-in on your site. My swim club's website kept crashing and we couldn't figure it out. Turns out there were a bunch of folders that had somehow been uploaded to our site. They appeared to contain music and video files. Since installing the anti-malware plug-in and deleting the offending directories, we haven't had any problems with our website. India is still the #1 source of traffic to our site, but all those visitors are getting 404 errors now. I've tried restricting visitors from India and a few other countries, but they're still getting through. Not sure how long it will take for them to get the point that their music and videos are no longer there.